# SQL hangs when executed as SP but is fine as SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Greetings,
I have been analyzing a problem with a delete stored procedure. The procedure simply performs a cascading delete of a certain entity.

When I break the SP out into SQL in the query editor it runs in approx. 7 seconds, however, when the SP is executed via EXEC SP it takes over 1 minute to execute.

I have tried the following with no luck:

- Dropped the SP and then recreated it using WITH RECOMPILE
- Added SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
- The SQL runs in the editor with many concurrent connections without issue.
- The EXEC Procedure hangs with or without concurrent connections

The procedure is similar to:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DELETE_Something]
    (
        @SomethingID INT,
        @Result INT OUT,
        @ResultMessage NVARCHAR(1000) OUT
    )--WITH RECOMPILE--!!!DEBUGGING
    AS

    --SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED--!!!DEBUGGING

    SET @Result=1
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY

        DELETE FROM XXXXX --APPROX. 34 Records
        DELETE FROM XXXX  --APPROX. 227 Records         
        DELETE FROM XXX   --APPROX. 58 Records  
        DELETE FROM XX    --APPROX. 24 Records      
        DELETE FROM X     --APPROX. 14 Records  

        DELETE FROM A -- 1 Record
        DELETE FROM B -- 1 Record
        DELETE FROM C -- 1 Record

        DELETE FROM D --APROX. 3400 Records !!!HANGS FOR OVER ONE MINUTE TRACING THROUGH SP BUT NOT SQL

        GOTO COMMIT_TRANS   

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
        GOTO ROLLBACK_TRANS
    END CATCH       

    COMMIT_TRANS:
        SET @Result=1   
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        RETURN  

    ROLLBACK_TRANS: 
        SET @Result=0
        SET @ResultMessage=CAST(ERROR_MESSAGE() AS NVARCHAR(1000))
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your statistics are up to date. Assuming the DELETE statements have some reference to the parameters getting passed, you might try the [OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) option, if you are using SQL 2008.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the optimize option for a statement in the sp against a table with many indexes and the problem was solved! So what solved the issue? WITH RECOMPILE, OPTIMIZE or some combination thereof.  Unfortunately, I had the recompile on at the same time I was using the OPTIMIZE option. 
When I back out to the original SP the problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This was more of a Parameter Sniffing (or Spoofing) issue. This is a rarely used SP. Using the OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) for a statement using  the parameter against a rather large table apparently solved the problem. Thank you [SqlACID](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19797/sqlacid) for the tip.

```
DELETE FROM 
   ProblemTableWithManyIndexes
WHERE                                   
   TableID=@TableID 
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

Answer (score 1):

As with any performance problem, you need to measure **why** it 'hangs'. Guessing will get you nowhere fast. Use a methodological approach, like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx). The simplest thing to do is look at `wait_type`, `wait_time` and `wait_resource` in [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx), for the request doing the exec sp, while it executes the sp. Based on what is actually causing the blockage, you can take appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply… I have already spent half a day analyzing the problem from this aspect. The process always executes in a run state with no wait types. When I spin up concurrent sessions they are blocked as expected for the duration of the command (not blocked).
 I switched to another server and am having the same issue.